# What is the difference between running a java/scala program via Intellij/Eclipse and running a jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

My code works fine if I "Run As" a scala program but when I create a jar file and run it there are some issues.

Can anyone guide how I go about trouble shooting it. It is a spark streaming code connecting to a kafka service.

```
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val batchInterval = 5

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("test")
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(batchInterval))

    ssc.receiverStream(
      ReceiverFactory.createReceiver(
          "host-name",
          "end-point",
          "stream-name",
          classOf[JsonNode],
          batchInterval
        )
      )
      .map(_.getPayload.toString)
      .foreachRDD(rdd => println("*** getting a count of RDD " + rdd.count()))


    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you create an uber jar? What exactly is the problem or error? Also, not seeing any Kafka code here

Comment: @cricket_007 - do you mean jar-with-dependencies? Yes I have done that.

Comment: Okay, that's the correct file. The only other difference would be that Intellij doesn't run `spark-submit`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your looking for a fat jar.

"Run as" in IDE's will set the classpath and some other options to the executed jvm process.

A fat jar will package all your class files and the dependencies to one jar file which is able to execute with "java -jar FAT.jar"

I know two good packager for this case

SBT-Assembly - https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

and

SBT Native Packager - https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

I hope that answer your question